# I changed the path of python3.6 to install a newer version of it, now I can't start my terminal

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I don't have any other terminal-like applications and I can't use my recovery console at CTRL + ALT + F2-F4 because It doesn't accept my password and it says incorrect. I don't know what to do, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you shouldn't mess around with the python version that comes with Ubuntu, that tends to break a lot of things.

If you need a newer version of python set it in the virtual environment of your project.

Comment: Do you know how can I fix the issue? Maybe a rollback or something?

Comment: Can I keep my personal files while doing so?

Comment: try this: https://www.fosslinux.com/2920/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-by-keep-your-data-safe-in-event-of-system-failure.htm